# Maui TabbedPage tabmode:Scrollbar not working

Tags: tabs, tabbedpage

In MAUI TabbedPage tabmode:Scrollbar is not working, all tabs are coming in fixed mode. How to solve this issue?

Added Tabbar.axml file in Platform/Resources/Android/Layout/Tabbar.axml.

Added below code in project file also,

`<ItemGroup> <AndroidResource Include="Platforms\Android\Resources\layout\Tabbar.axml" /> </ItemGroup>`

Tabbar.axml code is below,

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#000000" android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"  app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" app:tabGravity="fill" app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance" app:tabMode="scrollable" />`